# Why not load my external content in a HTML wih jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML page with a vertical menu. I would like to click on a menu item to open between div tag content item.

This is the HTML

```
 <div id="navigation">
  <ul id="list-links">
    <li ><a id="pollo" href="">Pollo</a></li>
    <li><a id="tacchino" href="">Tacchino</a></li>
    <li><a id="prodotti" href="">Prodotti</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="contentPro">

</div>

     </div>
```

And this the JS:

```
        $('#list-links li a' ).click(function(){  
        $clicked = $(this);
        var idToLoad = $clicked.attr("id")
        var url=idToLoad+'.html';

         $('#contentPro').load(url);

});
```

Why the external HTML don't load between  DIV tag??thanks

Comment: He wants the div, contentPro, to be loaded with the html that's supposed to be loaded from JQuery (as far as i can tell)

Comment: It strongly depends on the URL - you might be having cross domain request here.

Comment: yes, sorry.Why the external HTML don't load between DIV tag?

Comment: Open the console (F12) and type `$('#contentPro').load("pollo.html")` to test it.  Let us know what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your code inside `ready` event like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#list-links li a' ).click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        $clicked = $(this);
        var idToLoad = $clicked.attr("id")
        var url=idToLoad+'.html';
        $('#contentPro').load(url);
     });
});
```

Comment: ... hehehe Thanks! this was the problem.. but i don't understand why.. because i hve this code inside other "ready". Now I have put this code in another ready apart and works..

Answer (score 0):

When you click on anchor tag `<a>` page gets redirected. You have to stop that action using `event.preventDefault();`

Here is the updated code

```
$('#list-links li a' ).click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();       
        $clicked = $(this);
        var idToLoad = $clicked.attr("id")
        var url=idToLoad+'.html';

        $('#contentPro').load(url);
});
```

If the problem is not solved then you should check whether the path for `pollo.html`, `tacchino.html` and `prodotti.html` is correct?

Comment: It doesn't get redirected if the `href` value is empty.

Comment: @Archer It does reload/redirect, check here, http://jsfiddle.net/muthkum/VNB5N/1/